How do I fix this AttributeError on Glitch.com?
I made the discord.py bot that prevents spam and times out the user if the user doesn't stop spamming, but there's one problem: I always get AttributeError about Member and timeout. The error said the object "Member" doesn't have the attribute "timeout". Does anyone have a solution? Here's the error I always get and the block of the script with a problem. Surely I coded the script correctly, sorry if I made a very dumb mistake or a duplicated question. Thank you!
The error I always get:
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 80, in on_message
    await spam_active(message)
  File "bot.py", line 44, in spam_active
    await message.author.timeout(timedelta(minutes = 7), reason="Spamming")
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Part of the code with a problem
async def spam_active(message):
    global last_message_time, spam_warnings
    cooldown = 1.5
    timeout_threshold = 3
    current_time = time.time()
    author_id = message.author.id

    if author_id in last_message_time:
        if current_time - last_message_time[author_id] < cooldown:
            if author_id in spam_warnings:
                spam_warnings[author_id] += 1
            else:
                spam_warnings[author_id] = 1

            if spam_warnings[author_id] >= timeout_threshold:
                del last_message_time[author_id]
                del spam_warnings[author_id]
                await message.author.send("You've been timed out for spamming.")
                await message.author.timeout(timedelta(minutes = 7), reason="Spamming")
                return
            if message.author != bot.user:
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} Warning: Don't spam!")
            else:
                print("Bot cannot mute itself.")
        else:
            last_message_time[author_id] = current_time
            if author_id in spam_warnings:
                del spam_warnings[author_id]
    else:
        last_message_time[author_id] = current_time

Here are some failed attempts that none of them helped:
Asked the friend who makes the discord.py bot as well (Unfortunately friend didn't know how to fix)
Checked the spelling mistakes (All of them are spelled correctly)
Checked all articles about how to fix an AttributeError (None of the articles I checked helped after all, unfortunately...)
EDIT: I tried to do that with Replit, but somehow it worked, but I want to use it with Glitch. I meant does anyone how to solve this error on Glitch?

I tried it myself, and it works, at least this part:
await message.author.send("You've been timed out for spamming.")
await message.author.timeout(timedelta(minutes = 7), reason="Spamming")

I noticed you're using:

File "/app/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py"

I would suggest updating to the lastest version of python but probably more importantly the lastest version of discord.py.
It should also be noted that when I write it, the timeout function is yellow, indicating that the python interpreter found it.
When I alt+click it, it brings me to the function that proves this version of discord py and its Member class, does have the timeout function:
